# Is there any content management system api that can integrate with azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any content management system(like slideshare, with REST api access to connect and query the data or search for content) that can integrate with azure search cognitive services?

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but you can use [AzSearch.js](https://github.com/jj09/AzSearch.js) to build simple website for browsing your data stored in Azure Search Index. It's extensible and customizable.

Checkout [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Building-Search-Apps-with-Azure-Search-and-AzSearchjs) for more details.

BTW: what are you trying to build?

Comment: Thanks Jacob! So, I am trying to build a solution that will help me to integrate a content management system or some tool (like sharepoint for example) to MS Bot and retrieve/search the data from that CMS.